# How do I search for a particular file in a directory using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file in a directory and i want to pick one particular file from the directory at a time.

Code is given below:

```
$xml_file_name = <STDIN>;
chomp ($xml_file_name);

@o = file_search($xml_file_name);
print "file::@o\n";

sub file_search
{
    opendir (DIR, "/home/sait11/Desktop/test/Test cases") or die "Failed to open directory\n";
    @dirs_found = grep { /$xml_file_name/ } readdir DIR;
    closedir (DIR);
#   print "dir ::@dirs_found\n";
    return @dirs_found;
}
```

I am inputting the file name to be returned as `sample.xml`. But in the `@dirs_found` variable, all the file names that starts with 's' are getting stored.

How to find out the exact one file at a time?

Comment: You should use 'use warnings;' and 'use strict;' while you're learning Perl, because they help you catch mistakes you don't know you can make.  When you're an expert, you use 'use warnings;' and 'use strict;' reflexively, because they help you catch silly mistakes.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler What is your opinion on `use diagnostics;` instead of `use warnings;` for beginners?  I am always ambivalent.  It gives you more information, but then again it gives you **more information**.

Comment: @Chas: the recommendations are always 'use warnings;' and 'use strict;' - I was not aware of 'use diagnostics;' until you asked.  However, the Perl 5.12.1 manual says diagnostics is in the core, and the date at the bottom of the page is 1995, so it has been around forever (almost).  Since it seems to make 'use warnings;' more intelligible, but does not provide new functionality, I don't think it matters if you use diagnostics instead of warnings - but I doubt if I will change.  The key point is to have Perl help you as much as possible.

Comment: I usually advise beginners to look up their errors in [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) instead -- like reading the dictionary, it helps to gain exposure to the *other* kinds of errors that can occur as well as the one at giving trouble at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find a specific file, simply open the file, or run a file test on it:

```
my $file = "/home/sait11/Desktop/test/Test cases/$xml_file_name";

print "$file found\n" if -f $file;
```

Running your code, it certainly seems to work.  If you enter a pattern, then it correctly picks up the file names from the target directory that match that Perl regex you type in.  What name were you looking for?

If you revise the `grep` to read:

```
my @dirs_found = grep { /^$xml_file_name$/ } readdir DIR;
```

then it will exclude values where the regex doesn't match the entire name.  On the other hand, you give up some flexibility when you do that.

Answer (score -4):

Got the answer, i have to give the entire file name, so that it matches that particular file only.

Comment: huh? You know the full path already? If so, you dont have to search, just use -f $file as @Jonathan suggested