# Why do I get a number instead a list of filenames from readdir?

Tags: perl, directory

I have a piece of Perl code for searchnig a directory and display the contents of that directory, if match is found. The code is given below:

```
$test_case_directory = "/home/sait11/Desktop/SaLT/Data_Base/Test_Case";
$xml_file_name = "sample.xml"

$file_search_return = file_search($xml_file_name);
print "file search return::$file_search_return\n";


sub file_search
{
    opendir (DIR, $test_case_directory) or die "\n\tFailed to open directory that contains the test case xml files\n\n";

    print "xml_file_name in sub routines:: $xml_file_name\n";

    $dirs_found = grep { /^$xml_file_name/i } readdir DIR;
    print "Files in the directory are dirs_found :: $dirs_found\n";
    closedir (DIR);
    return $dirs_found;
}
```

Output is,

```
xml_file_name in sub routines:: sample.xml
Files in the directory are dirs_found :: 1
file search return::1
```

It is not returning the file name found. Instead it returns the number 1 always.

I don't know why it is not returning the file name called `sample.xml` present in the directory.

Comment: For easier ways to read the content of a directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772001.

Comment: `readdir` is not returning anything 'wrongly'. The way you think `grep` works does not match how `grep` works in reality. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

Comment: You really need to turn on `use strict; use warnings;`. It's going to save you from many headaches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I search for a particular file in a directory using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667280/how-do-i-search-for-a-particular-file-in-a-directory-using-perl)

Comment: Curiously, we already answered this very question for you, and it's almost exactly the same code.

Comment: same code... but different questions ... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
($dirs_found) = grep { /^$xml_file_name/i } readdir DIR; #capture it
```

Problem was that, you were evaluating the `grep` as *scalar context*, change it to *list context* will give you the desired result.

In **scalar context**, `grep` returns the number of times the expression was true.

In **list context**, it returns the elements for which the expression was true.

Answer (score 8):

[perldoc grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) says:

> In scalar context, returns the number of times the expression was true.

And that's exactly what you are doing. So you found 1 file and that result is assigned to `$dirs_found` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you opening a directory and looking for a particular filename? If you want to see if the file is there, just test for it directly:

```
 use File::Spec::Functions;
 my $file = catfile( $test_case_directory, $xml_file_name );
 if( -e $file ) { ... }
```

When you run into these sorts of problems, though, check the result at each step to check what you are getting. Your first step would decompose the problem statement:

```
 my @files = readdir DIR;
 print "Files are [@files]\n";

 my $filtered = grep { ... } @files;
 print "Files are [$filtered]\n";
```

Once you do that you see that the problem is `grep`. Once you know that the problem is `grep`, you read its documentation, notice that you are using it wrong, and you're done sooner than it would take to post a question on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

you should say `@dirs_found`, not `$dirs_found`